# Parsing web-site

Tags: html, parsing

So, I have a web-site. The links have a following structure: `http://example.com/1`, `http://example.com/2`, `http://example.com/3`, etc. Each of this pages has a simple table. So how can I download automatically every single page on my computer? Thanks.

P.S. I know that some of you may tell me to google it. But I don't know what I'm actually looking for (I mean what to type in search field).

Comment: Google for "screen scraping". And are you asking how to write a program to download those pages?

Comment: should be posted on superuser

Answer (score 3):

use`wget (http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/ )` to scrape the site

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `wget` command line tool. It will let you download and save web pages.

Beyond that, your question is too broad for the Stack Overflow community to be of much help.

Comment: Almost _any_ programming language used today is able to download an HTML file and there are usually a large number of ways to do it even within one language. The question of "How do I download a website?" is just that...too broad. Please check out how to ask a question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple app and loop through all the urls and pull down the html.  For a Java example, take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html